# copy word between specific words and paste in another line in the same file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Text :

```
 this *is the* string. 
 this word i want.
```

Output :

```
   this *is the* string
   this *is the* word i want
```

How can I copy "*is the*" from "this is the string" and paste it between "*this word*" using either the `sed` or `awk` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use `awk` for a solution to this kind of problem, and since you tagged the question with `awk` in addition to `sed`, here's an `awk` answer:

```
awk 'NR==1{data=$2 " " $3}NR==2{$2=data " " $2}{print}'
```

Missing from your question was guidance how to identify the items to copy, and how you want to identify the position to paste. So, in my answer I took the liberty of assuming you were scanning a first line for its second and third words, with intent to paste them after the first word of the second line.

Comment: thanks its working. actually i have multiple pair of the input text inside the file. do you know how to loop this awk command? so i can get the same output for other same line.

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it as correct! If you have another question, you should really post a separate question. To answer your second question anyway, you don't need a "loop"; you can identify all odd lines in `awk` by replacing `NR==1` with just `NR%2` (that's a modulus 2 operation) and all even lines by replacing `NR==2` with `!NR%2`. Also, I edited your question to make it more clear, so please also mark that accepted if it is correct.